# Pipe from Linux VM to Mac

Tags: linux, macos, pipe

I tried creating a pipe on a Mac host using `mkfifo` and reading from a Linux VM.

I encountered some issues with concurrent reading and writing and am wondering if there are other ways to make a one-way concurrent read write pipe between Mac and Linux?

Is this even a proper use of pipes?

The pipe resides in a location accessible by the Linux VM.

Answer (score 0):

[Netpipes](http://web.purplefrog.com/~thoth/netpipes/netpipes.html) by Robert Forsman is an elegant solution to this problem. It uses a hose and faucet metaphor to mimic pipes functionality across tcp streams. Netpipes is available as a macports package for Mac OS X besides the usual *nix versions.

Say you want to transfer a whole bunch of files from your Linux VM to your Mac OSX host using pipes, run these shell commands in their respective shells:

```
 LINUXVM$ faucet 2222 --out tar cf - .
 OSXHOST$ hose server 2222 --in tar xvf -
```

2222 is the port number. See the man pages for tunneling and relaying through firewalls and other modern hurdles.